# Nexpose consumes 16GB RAM and is slow with 3.3GHz quad core

Tags: memory, cpu, performance

Nexpose vulnerability scanner was using too much RAM to run locally on my laptop, so I got it a high performance VPS that well exceeds its requirements. The Debian 10 server has 18GB RAM, 3.3GHz CPU cores, and no other apps running.

It (kinda) works, but after only a day it has become unusably slow. In fact, the UI is mostly not responsive unless you know the URI path of the page you want and type it in.

It's not even running any scans or reports. I've tried restarting. Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot or help it work more efficiently?

I did run a couple of scans previously, but those have long since completed and actually the app was working much better before and during those scans than it is now.

Steps tried:

1. Restarting
2. `garbagecollect`
3. `database diagnostics` - did not show any problems
4. `diag` - did not show any problems

At the time of writing it shows 7GB of available RAM (out of the 18) and only 2% CPU usage.

Comment: It is commercial software. have you tried reaching out to Rapid7 about it? Note that these kinds of tools can be slow because they are probing for things that are not there, and as a result must wait for timeouts. the faster it runs, the more half-open items it has to track at any given time. Just a thought.

Comment: @FrankThomas Good points. I did reach out but it's a free trial so I think the answer is "buy it then we'll help". I was thinking the same about your 2nd comment but I expected restarting to fix that.

Comment: Give us some detail on what the system resources are during this period of slow response.  Even with a trial, you should still contact the company. Without knowing if this your system is low on memory or your CPU utilization is extremely it will be difficult for anyone to answer your question.  Details like what operating system you are using should be contained within the question instead of a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, added the OS name to the question body. The total RAM was there but also added CPU usage and how much RAM is currently available. I did reach out to the company again but no reply as of yet and they don't provide support for free accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was the browser. Apparently, Nexpose only works well with Chrome (or Chromium).

Incompatibilities with FireFox mimicks the symptoms you'd expect if the app/server resources were overloaded.